# how to load the city spinner against state spinner in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to set the city spinner against the state spinner. I have taken 2 spinner one for state and other  for city. When i select the state in state spinner i want to get the all the list of city in city spinner.Can u help me to solve this.Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StateCity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_45"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_25"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="state"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerState"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_50"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="city"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_50"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
    public class StateCity extends BaseActivity {

        Spinner spinnerState, spinnerCity;

        ArrayList<GetState> stateArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<CityListModel> cityArray = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayAdapter<CityListModel> arrayAdapterCT;

        int state_id;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_state_city);


            stateArray = new ArrayList<>();
            cityArray = new ArrayList<>();


            spinnerState = findViewById(R.id.spinnerState);
            spinnerCity = findViewById(R.id.spinnerCity);

            getLocalState();
            //getLocalCity();


        }

        @Override
        protected String getTag() {
            return "StateCity";
        }
        private void getLocalState() {
            long count = LocalStateModel.count(LocalStateModel.class);
            if (count > 0) {
                stateArray.add(new GetState(0, "Select State"));
                List<LocalStateModel> localStateModels = new LocalStateModel().listAll(LocalStateModel.class);
                for (int i = 0; i < localStateModels.size(); i++) {
                    stateArray.add(new GetState(localStateModels.get(i).getState_id(), localStateModels.get(i).getName()));
                }
                setSpinner();
            }
        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void getLocalCity() {
            long count = LocalCityModel.count(LocalCityModel.class);
            if (count > 0) {
                //cityArray.add(new CityListModel(0, "Select City"));
                List<LocalCityModel> localCityModels = new LocalCityModel().listAll(LocalCityModel.class);
                cityArray.add(new CityListModel(0, "Select City"));

                for (int i = 0; i < localCityModels.size(); i++) {
                    cityArray.add(new CityListModel(localCityModels.get(i).getCity_id(), localCityModels.get(i).getCity_name()));
                }
                setCitySpinner();
            }

        }



        public void setSpinner(){
            final ArrayAdapter<GetState> arrayAdapter14 = new ArrayAdapter<GetState>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stateArray) {
                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    if (position == 0) {

                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                    if (position == 0) {
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    return view;
                }
            };
            arrayAdapter14.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
            spinnerState.setAdapter(arrayAdapter14);

            spinnerState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (position > 0) {
                        GetState getType = (GetState) parent.getSelectedItem();
                        /*ArrayList<CityListModel> tempCity = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (CityListModel getState : cityArray) {
                            if (getState.getState_id() == getType.getState_id()) {
                                tempCity.add(getState);
                            }

                            arrayAdapterCT = new ArrayAdapter<CityListModel>(StateCity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, tempCity);
                            arrayAdapterCT.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
                            spinnerCity.setAdapter(arrayAdapterCT);
                        }*/


                            /*MyApplication.getInstance().addIntToSharedPreference(STATE_TYPE1, getType.getState_id());
                            state_id = getType.getState_id();*/
                            //getLocalCity();
                            //setCitySpinner();
                           //setCitySpinner();


                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });


        }

        public void setCitySpinner(){
            final ArrayAdapter<CityListModel> arrayAdapter17 = new ArrayAdapter<CityListModel>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cityArray) {
                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    if (position == 0) {

                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                    if (position == 0) {
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    return view;
                }
            };
            arrayAdapter17.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
            spinnerCity.setAdapter(arrayAdapter17);

            spinnerCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    CityListModel getType = (CityListModel) parent.getSelectedItem();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

        }
    }



    enter code here

    public class CityListModel implements Serializable {
        int id, state_id;
        String city_name;

        public CityListModel(int id, String city_name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.city_name = city_name;
        }


        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getState_id() {
            return state_id;
        }

        public void setState_id(int state_id) {
            this.state_id = state_id;
        }

        public String getCity_name() {
            return city_name;
        }

        public void setCity_name(String city_name) {
            this.city_name = city_name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return city_name;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(obj instanceof CityListModel){
                CityListModel c = (CityListModel) obj;
                if(c.getId() == id && c.getCity_name().equals(city_name) )
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    enter code here

     public class GetState  implements Serializable {
        int state_id ;
        String name, user_id;
        List<GetCity> city;

        public GetState(int state_id, String name) {
            this.state_id = state_id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public GetState() {

        }


        public int getState_id() {
            return state_id;
        }

        public void setState_id(int state_id) {
            this.state_id = state_id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getUser_id() {
            return user_id;
        }

        public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
            this.user_id = user_id;
        }

        public List<GetCity> getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(List<GetCity> city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(obj instanceof GetState){
                GetState c = (GetState) obj;
                if(c.getState_id() == state_id && c.getName().equals(name) )
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just give you an hint how to do that

```
String[] state = {"state 1","state 2","state 3"};
String[] car = {"car 1","car 2","car 3"};
String[] category = {"state","car"};
```

And this is how it works

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,category);
    sp1.setAdapter(adapter);

    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String Value = category[position];
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (Value.contentEquals("state")){
                ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,state);
                sp2.setAdapter(adapter1);
            }else if (Value.contentEquals("car")){
                ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,car);
                sp2.setAdapter(adapter1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Hopes this is what you asked for

Comment: thank u sir for your response bt i want it for dynamic data getting from json response